# Почему не работает функция playPause для видео html5?

Tags: javascript, html, видео

Вставил видео на сайт, необходимо сделать кнопку проигрывания и паузы для видео, чтобы при закрытии модального окна, видео не играло, но это почему то не работает, вот код который я использовал:

html:

```
<video id="video1" src="video/Nyan-Cat-video.mp4" controls></video>
<button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
```

javascript:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
function playPause() { 
if (myVideo.paused) 
  $('#video1').get(0).play()
else 
  $('#video1').get(0).pause() 
}
```

Comment: правильно `myVideo.play()` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_play_pause отсюда http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp

Comment: Отпишу по сабжу, как все таки решить проблему. функцию playPause() надо выносить за тело doc ready. как и определение переменой в видео var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); тогда будет работать и onclick. (так же была индивидуальная ошибка моего кода (крашился js файл))

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39255/discussion-on-question-by-maggot-brain-----playpause-).

Answer (score 1):

Еще одно решение взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378199/uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-with-onclick

Там пишут: никогда не используйте .onclick()  из документа.

Тогда обновленный код будет таковой:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <button type="button" id="butPlay">
    Play Video
  </button>

  <video id="myVideo" src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" width="320" height="176" controls></video>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("butPlay").addEventListener("click", playPause, false);

    function playPause() {
      var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
      if (myVideo.paused)
        myVideo.play();
      else
        myVideo.pause();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: почему то все равно не работает, на этот раз даже без ошибок каких либо

Comment: Отпишу по сабжу, как все таки решить проблему. функцию playPause() надо выносить за тело doc ready. как и определение переменой в видео 

var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

тогда будет работать и onclick. 

(так же была индивидуальная ошибка моего кода (крашился js файл))

Comment: @maggotbrain  мдее..... вам азы на срочно идти учить........ ведь функции на то и функции что они должны быть объявлены до всякого построения дом дерева............притом пример от Jean-Claude  наглядно показывает что нет никаких DomReady............охххх.......